# Is there any research that compares Likert scale questions to "satisfaction" scale questions?

Tags: references, survey, likert, scales, psychometrics

I'm trying to put together a questionnaire for measuring employee satisfaction with an internal process.

I'd like to figure out if there is reason to prefer:

```
I think the process is simple: <agree ---- disagree> (Likert scale)
```

to

```
I would describe the process as: <simple ---- hard>
```

I'm a little at a loss on what to Google, since I don't know the formal name for the second scale or even where to start looking.

Is there a difference here? Or is it much of a muchness?

Comment: That might be similar to a [semantic differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_differential) scale.

Comment: @gung I think that might be it! I got some very interesting hits searching for "likert scale vs semantic differential scale". If you can turn this into an answer, I will readily accept it!

Comment: You're welcome. There are people here (not me) who are experts in psychometrics. They may be able to point you towards specific research that will be more helpful to you. It may take a day or two, though. If the Q goes otherwise unanswered, I can convert my comment to an answer, but it isn't really much of an answer.